# Storing cookies by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to store a cookie with the name "show" and the value "no" when a checkbox has been marked and a submit-button has been clicked. Could someone tell me why this script won't work?

```
$(".hideins").click(function () {
    if ($('.sshow').is(':checked')) {
        function set_cookie("hide", "no", 7) {
            var domain_string = valid_domain ? ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '';
            document.cookie = cookie_name +
                "=" + encodeURIComponent(cookie_value) +
                "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * lifespan_in_days +
                "; path=/" + domain_string;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: you are not invoking the set_cookie function

Comment: That's not how functions work.

Comment: also look at the jQuery cookie plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: See : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Sorry guys, kinda new at this...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a (working) `set_cookie` function elsewhere, and just call it, not define the entire function inside the event handler :

```
$(".hideins").click(function () {
    if ($('.sshow').is(':checked')) {
        set_cookie("hide", "no", 7);
    }
});


function set_cookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Comment: @phpdev - should work just fine, the name is "hide", as that is what it was in the OP's code, even if it says in the question that the name should be "show", but that's not really the issue, just a discrepancy

Comment: ive upvoted yours.. i was going to answer the same, but got stuck at one part(what i commented first)..

Comment: @phpdev - thanks, not sure why it was downvoted to begin with, seems to answer the question in my opinion ?

Comment: yep.. I was about to answer the same, but then you type extremely quick or i type like a turtle.. Think OP got it to work and should be accepting it...